# How to call a function from a variable module in Python?

Tags: python

I am having an issue trying to call a function from a variable module.

I have several scripts under a "scripts/" folder, and from outside this folder, I would like to call the `main()` function of one of my `scripts/module` inside, but this module name is variable.

Basically, I would like to do this (but this isn't possible in Python apparently):

```
scripts.{myModuleName}.main()
```

1. The `exec` command isn't fitting in my case, as it doesn't wait for the called script to finish properly:

   ```py
   exec("scripts." + myModuleName + ".main()")
   ```
2. The command `subprocess.run` isn't fitting as well because this is calling the full script and not the specific `main()` function I want. And `if __name__ == __main__` isn't preventing it.

   ```py
   my_command = "python scripts\\" + myModuleName
   subprocess.run(my_command, shell=True, check=True)
   ```

Any ideas?

--

EDIT: Thank you Gino, working well with importlib. Here is my code in case it could help someone:

```
import importlib
import os

#We will get, display and import all the scripts dropped into the 'scripts' folder
moduleList = []
for incr, myScript in enumerate(os.listdir('.\\scripts')):
    if ".py" in myScript:
        moduleList.append(importlib.import_module(f"scripts.{myScript.replace('.py','')}"))
        print(f"{incr+1} - {myScript}")

#Ask the user which script he wants to execute
userChoice = input("Choose the number of the script you want to execute: ")

#Execute the main of the desired script
try:
    moduleList[int(userChoice)-1].main()
except (IndexError, ValueError) as e:
    print("Error, you need to enter a number displayed above.")
```

Comment: `scripts.getattr(myModuleName).main()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)'s [`import_module(name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) function to import a module by name **as a string**:

> Import a module. The *name* argument specifies what module to import in absolute or relative terms (e.g. either `pkg.mod` or `..mod`).

```
module = importlib.import_module(f'scripts.{module_name}')
module.main()
```

In this way, the module name can be a variable and it can be dynamically defined or set in your program/script. Then, once you've got the module, you can just call its `main()` function (or any other function or variable on that module).

If we have this directory structure (similar to what you said "*I have several scripts under a "scripts/" folder*".):

```
$ tree .
.
├── outside.py
└── scripts
    ├── module1.py
    ├── module2.py
    └── module3.py
```

And each moduleN.py has a `main` like this:

```
def main():
    print('Called main from module3')
```

Then to do "*from outside this folder, I would like to call the main() function of one of my script/module inside*", you can have outside.py receive the name of the module like this:

```
import importlib
import sys

module_name = sys.argv[1]
print(f'Calling "main" from {module_name}')

module = importlib.import_module(f'scripts.{module_name}')
module.main()
```

```
$ python outside.py module1
Calling "main" from module1
Called main from module1

$ python outside.py module2
Calling "main" from module2
Called main from module2

$ python outside.py module3
Calling "main" from module3
Called main from module3
```

Do take note that `import_module(name)` works much the same way as the standard `import module_name`, such that it depends on from where you are running this import code. Meaning, `import_module('scripts.module1')` will work if `import scripts.module1` works.